# Jsp serverlet mapping url-pattern /* overrides the welcome-file

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I'm building a site on Google app engine with Java.
There I'm trying to map jsp pages with servlet mapping as follows:

`http://localhost:8080/<any text>` should map to `r.jsp`

`http://localhost:8080` should map to `home.jsp`

*But those two urls always get mapped to `r.jsp`.*

And my web.xml is as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>r</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/r.jsp</jsp-file>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>r</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I also tried `<url-pattern>""</url-pattern>` instead of `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` and it also did not work

Any **servlet mapping solution** for this?

Answer (score 1):

Change you web.xml to something like this

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>r</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/r.jsp</jsp-file>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>r</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ewerw</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>r</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rrrxdsfwef</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>r</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/xy1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Hi, Avinash. now `http://localhost:8080` is mapping to `home.jsp`. 
And `http://localhost:8080/test/xy1` is mapped to `r.jsp`. Is there a way to map `http://localhost:8080/xy1` to `r.jsp` without alterring home page mapping. Or is this the only solution ?

Comment: Yes, you could do it. replace <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern> with <url-pattern>/xy1</url-pattern>

Comment: Sorry I asked it in the wrong way, I want all `http://localhost:8080/xy1` or `http://localhost:8080/rrrxdsfwef` or `http://localhost:8080/ewerw` to map to `r.jsp` while `http://localhost:8080` is mapped to home.jsp

Comment: In that case you could use the multiple servlet mapping. I have updated the answer, it might work for you. Also i would suggest you to go through the basics of servlet mapping before jumping to coding. http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/